# DocuSign automatic reminders for signing the template using PHP and Laravel API

Tags: php, laravel-8, docusignapi

How can I write PHP code to set DocuSign automatic reminders for signing the template using PHP and Laravel API

Comment: I would expect you can check Docusign's features in the Docusign documentation? Or by asking their marketing people? At Stackoverflow we can help you with programming problems, not with product support. See also [ask] and the [tour]. Unless you've just worded it very badly, it's unclear how your question relates to programming, or to PHP specifically. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this using PHP
https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-common-api-tasks-add-reminders-and-expiration-to-an-envelope talks about it in detail, an example PHP code for this is:

```
$envelopeDefinition = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\EnvelopeDefinition();
$notification = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Notification();
$notification->setUseAccountDefaults('false'); # customize the notification for this envelope
$reminders = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Reminders();
$reminders->setReminderEnabled('true');
$reminders->setReminderDelay('3');  # first reminder to be sent three days after envelope was sent
$reminders->setReminderFrequency('2'); # keep sending reminders every two days
$expirations = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Expirations();
$expirations->setExpireEnabled('true');
$expirations->setExpireAfter('30');  # envelope will expire after 30 days
$expirations->setExpireWarn('2');  # expiration reminder would be sent two days before expiration
$notification->setExpirations($expirations);
$notification->setReminders($reminders);
$envelopeDefinition->setNotification($notification);
```

Comment: Thanks for you edit my question and mark as a valid question